# f.label está sobrepondo as informações que estão em f.text_field

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

```
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <%= f.label "Número do SUS" %>
    <%=f.text_field :sus_number %>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <%= f.label "Paciente"%>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'form-control' %>
  </div>
```

[image: Como fica na edição]

Comment: Como arrumar isso?

Comment: Tenta utilizar uma tag de quebra de linha entre eles

Comment: Não funcionou. Usei <br></br> e nada

Comment: isso aparenta ser problema de CSS e não do rails.

Comment: <br> é uma tag orfã, isto é, não existe uma correspondente de fechamento (como o <p></p>).